# has_many conditions with an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements, has-many

I have the following models:

```
Trip -> has_many trip_members & belongs_to user
Trip -> has_many shares
Share -> belongs_to user
```

In my trip model, I'm setting up a relationship like this

```
has_many :shares, :conditions => proc { |user| {:user_id => user.id} }
```

so that I always have a user associated with the share. I'm trying to access this by passing in a user object in the call to trip.shares(user), but that doesn't seem to work. How does this passing argument to proc work ?

Also, is this the right way to setup a condition ? I thought of overriding the generated methods (such as trip.shares<< etc) to include the user passed in as an argument, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to say that a user `has_many :trips, :through => :shares` instead?

Comment: @CodeGnome it's a little different. A trip will be created by a user, but it will have many trip_members, and each trip_member can share the trip with n number of people. Trip members and the people this trip is shared with are not the same. I'll try and be more clear in my question

Answer (score 0):

Conditions do not change the behavior of creating associated objects.  They only limit the results queried from the database.

```
trip.shares.create(:user => user)
```

Comment: are you sure ? I thought that conditions also come into picture when you create also. Isn't that the finder_sql's job that you mention ? I actually want to be able to have this condition included in all my code conditions (not just specifically for find only). Any way around it ??

Comment: What I understand is that you can create members in associations which do not meet the conditions.  I don't think there is an effect on creation.

Comment: It mentions in the rails guide that hash conditions are also used during create & build operations. Of course only if you go through the model. I'm lost here !